# Automapper: Unexpected mapping behavior using nullable type

Tags: c#, automapper

With Automapper (6.6.2) I'm trying to map a nullable boolean to a destinations object property (dest.IsEnabled.Value).
But as soon the source value is null, the entire destination property (dest.IsEnabled) is null. But I only expect the property "value" to be null.

Any idea how to do it right?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = new Source();
        source.IsEnabled = null;

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
                //.ConstructUsing(ctor => new Dest());
            cfg.CreateMap<bool?, IsEnabledProperty>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
        });

        //var debug = config.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(Source), typeof(Dest));

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        //var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source, new Dest());
        var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source);

        if (dest.IsEnabled == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IsEnabled is null. But why? I expect IsEnabled.Value to be null.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Source
{
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

class Dest
{
    public IsEnabledProperty IsEnabled { get; set; } 
        = new IsEnabledProperty() { IsRequired = true };

    // Just to check if the property is initialized
    public OtherProperty OtherProperty { get; set; }
        = new OtherProperty() { IsRequired = true };
}

class IsEnabledProperty
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool? Value { get; set; }
}

class OtherProperty
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool? Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

When I update the mapping like this

```
cfg.CreateMap<bool?, IsEnabledProperty>()
   .ConvertUsing((src, dst, context) => 
   {
      if (dst != null) 
         dst.Value = src;
      return dst;
   });
```

dest.IsEnabled.Value is mapped correctly for all variants (null, false, true), and also the property destination.IsEnabled.IsRequired has the initialized value of true, **but it forces me to pass an instance of destination to the mapping method**: `var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source, new Dest());`.
This doesn't make sense in my eyes, since I expect the destination object should be constructed the same way by automapper?

When looking at the execution plan, I'm asking me, why it checks for `(dest == null)` in line 11 and not just use the initialized `typeMapDestination`:

```
(src, dest, ctxt) =>
{
    Dest typeMapDestination;
    return (src == null)
        ? null
        : {
            typeMapDestination = dest ?? new Dest();
            try
            {
                var resolvedValue = ((src == null) || false) ? null : src.IsEnabled;
                var propertyValue = mappingFunction.Invoke(resolvedValue, (dest == null) ? null : typeMapDestination.IsEnabled, ctxt);
                typeMapDestination.IsEnabled = propertyValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new AutoMapperMappingException(
                    "Error mapping types.",
                    ex,
                    AutoMapper.TypePair,
                    TypeMap,
                    PropertyMap);
            };

            return typeMapDestination;
        };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to write this  `.ForMember(dst => dst.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsEnabled));` instead of `.ForMember(dst => dst.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));`

Comment: @CodeNotFound src is a Nullable<bool> in this case.

Comment: Make IsEnabledProperty a struct then.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Using a struct works for the value, but the initialized IsRequired property has the wrong value (false). Even if I pass in an initialized destination object to the mapping function.

Comment: Yes, you have to be careful with structs and copies. About the type converter, you get a destination only when you pass one because someone wanted that some time ago :) Different people have different expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to map the whole `bool?` instead of only the value `dest.IsEnabled.Value`. This way you can ask the boolean if it has a value with `dest.HasValue` and use the value with `dest.Value`.

You might want to add `AllowNullableMapping` to the Automapper configuration.